# Load ashmem & kmodsign

Tags: kernel, secure-boot, modprobe, anbox

I recently install Anbox on my Ubuntu 20.04. I found on the post [Module "ashmem" doesn't load with Secure Boot on (but "binder" does load with secure boot on)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267823/module-ashmem-doesnt-load-with-secure-boot-on-but-binder-does-load-with-se) that I need to load ashmem and binder. Loading binder is fine but I fail to load ahsmem.
Therefore, as suggested in the aforementioned post, I tried to run:

`` sudo kmodsign sha512 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/staging/android/ashmem_linux.ko ``

But in my case, this command raises the following error:

> At main.c:248:
>
> - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
> - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
>   kmodsign: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv: No such file or directory

Could anyone please help me here ?

Lucas

**EDIT**

I found on the page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot, the command:

`sudo update-secureboot-policy --new-key`

I can now run
`` sudo kmodsign sha512 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/staging/android/ashmem_linux.ko ``
without any error but `sudo modprobe ashmem_linux` still raises

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ashmem_linux': Operation not permitted