# Trying to fix "[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules." error messages on start up

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

## The Problem

On boot, I see a `[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.` error message.
As shown in the below images from my phone, as I am unable to enter the GUI of the OS and take a screenshot, I see:
[image: Error Message 1]
[image: Error Message 2]

### How It Started

I was having an issue with Python versions. I wanted to upgrade to 3.10 from 3.8 and simply thought I'd uninstall the older version and install the newer version. Then when restarting my laptop, these errors began to occur on boot.

## What I Have Tried

It is worth clarifying that I am able to gain a terminal by `Ctrl + Alt + F1` then I can log in with my usual user and password. This is all I have, I do not have access to any of the Ubuntu GUI, as previously mentioned.

As suggested in the error message, I checked `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` for details. This showed the following:

[image: systemctl output]

Which led to some Googling and I found the following suggestions that sadly did not work for me.

### Attempted Solution 1

I initially found and tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules) which suggested running:

```
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
```

This seemed to fix some initial errors that were coming up with python modules, however it does not fix the `ashmem_linux` issue which has persisted.

### Attempted Solution 2

This led to me Googling specific issues related to `ashmem_linux`, leading to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267823/module-ashmem-doesnt-load-with-secure-boot-on-but-binder-does-load-with-se) which suggested that the error to the modules not being signed. Running the following command should fix it:

```
kmodsign sha512 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/staging/android/ashmem_linux.ko
```

Sadly, this didn't make any difference for me and I get the same errors as shown in the above images.

### Attempted Solution 3

Further Googling led me to finding a [GitHub page](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1070) on some software called Anbox (didn't seem hugely relevant to me but I'm getting desperate at this point so it was worth a go). A workaround was posted on this [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS) that seemed promising but I don't think I can get to the BIOS without the Load Kernel Modules error popping up. I am perhaps doing something wrong there so I am willing to be told that I'm being stupid and should try it a subtly different way.

## My System

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS Focal Fossa.

***Thank you ahead of time for your help!***

Comment: If you tamper with the python version, you're in big trouble, since it is an integral part of the Ubuntu OS. There are many questions concerning 'I have removed or replaced python' in this forum. Try to restore the original python version, if that fails you need to reinstall .

Comment: Yeah, I was worried that might be the case. Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Python 3.8.5 out of the box. So you think of I do a ```sudo apt-get install python3.8```, that may fix my problem?

Comment: If you run `apt-cache madison python3` it will show you all the versions available to install for your version of Ubuntu.  Try to get as close to the original as you can.

Comment: @GBean: " restore python" in this forum will lead to 155 results.

Comment: Python seems to have been reinstalled. Running ```python3 -V``` informed me that it is on Python 3.10.

Comment: UPDATE: I gave up trying to fix it and just reinstalled Ubuntu from a USB. Everything is fine and dandy now!